# Error trying to use a Proxy in Python3

Tags: python, proxy

I'm trying to visit a url, each time using a different proxy, from a file, until all proxies have been used.  Getting errors:

```
socket.gaierror: [Errno 11004] getaddrinfo failed
urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error [Errno 11004] getaddrinfo failed>
```

proxies1 file has 300 lines like this:
34.195.146.122:80

```
import urllib.request
my_file = open("proxies1","r")
for n in my_file:
    proxy = urllib.request.ProxyHandler({'http': 'n'})
    opener = urllib.request.build_opener(proxy)
    urllib.request.install_opener(opener)
    urllib.request.urlretrieve('http://www.google.com')
```

Getting the following output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 1318, in do_open
    encode_chunked=req.has_header('Transfer-encoding'))
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\http\client.py", line 1239, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\http\client.py", line 1285, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\http\client.py", line 1234, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\http\client.py", line 1026, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\http\client.py", line 964, in send
    self.connect()
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\http\client.py", line 936, in connect
    (self.host,self.port), self.timeout, self.source_address)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\socket.py", line 704, in create_connection
    for res in getaddrinfo(host, port, 0, SOCK_STREAM):
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\socket.py", line 743, in getaddrinfo
    for res in _socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, flags):
socket.gaierror: [Errno 11004] getaddrinfo failed

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "p3.py", line 12, in <module>
    urllib.request.urlretrieve('http://www.google.com')
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 248, in urlretrieve
    with contextlib.closing(urlopen(url, data)) as fp:
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 223, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 526, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 544, in _open
    '_open', req)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 504, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 1346, in http_open
    return self.do_open(http.client.HTTPConnection, req)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 1320, in do_open
    raise URLError(err)
urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error [Errno 11004] getaddrinfo failed>
```